# sort a dictonary in datetime field

Tags: python, odoo-12

hello i have a code that gives me dict the dict here is the dict:

```
{2516: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 16, 10, 10, 461000), 'product_id': 2516, 
'product_name': 'TRENTO GRIS 30*60 NEW TILE SPAIN 514', 'quantity': -1.0, 'product_cost': 4.0,
'price_unit': 5.5, 'remaining_qty': -23.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد ابو فهد', 'jour': 'Cash,'},

2412: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 13, 59, 33, 351000), 'product_id': 2412, 
'product_name': 'ORION HEXA SILVER 19.8*22. SPAIN 355', 'quantity': -4.0, 'product_cost': 0.58, 
'price_unit': 1.25, 'remaining_qty': 129.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد برغش المطيري المحترم ', 'jour': 'Cash,'},

2897: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 4, 2, 939000), 'product_id': 2897, 'product_name': 'BLANCO BR RECT LA 30*60 SPAIN 456', 
'quantity': -6.0, 'product_cost': 3.5, 'price_unit': 4.0, 'remaining_qty': 6.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد احمد منصور العازمي', 
'jour': 'Cash,'},

 2828: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 8, 38, 380000), 
'product_id': 2828, 'product_name': 'كاونتر مدور رمادي فاتح 1277 (36*12 CM', 'quantity': -1.0, 'product_cost': 0.0, 
'price_unit': 27.5, 'remaining_qty': -1.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد علي المطيري المحترم', 'jour': 'Cash,'}, 

3041: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 7, 11, 189000), 'product_id': 3041, 'product_name': 'PRIS TINENZA 30*60 SPAIN', 
'quantity': -2.0, 'product_cost': 5.0, 'price_unit': 6.5, 'remaining_qty': -13.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد محمد حسن الكندري المحترم', 'jour': 'Cash,'}}
```

i tried list comprenhsion like:

```
                if products_sold.get(line.product_id.id):
                products_sold[line.product_id.id] = sorted([{
                    'order_date': order.date_order,
                    'product_id': products_sold[line.product_id.id].get('product_id'),
                    'product_name': products_sold[line.product_id.id].get('product_name'),
                    'quantity': products_sold[line.product_id.id].get('quantity', 0) + line.qty,
                    'product_cost': products_sold[line.product_id.id].get('product_cost'),
                    'price_unit': products_sold[line.product_id.id].get('price_unit'),
                    'remaining_qty': line.product_id.qty_available,
                    'seller_name': seller_name,
                    'jour': jour
                } for (product, seller_name, order, line, jour), qty in products_sold.get(line.product_id.id)],key=lambda l: l['order_date']
```

but each time i try this i get a error `"ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"`

I even tried like:

```
dict = {k: v for k, v in sorted(products_sold[line.product_id.id].items(), key= lambda v : v[0])}
```

and passed it in return still i get error

how to sort this above dictionary i am getting no idea  any help will be appreciated, below is a method in which i want the dict to be sorted by `"order_date"`:

```
    def get_sale_details_product_wise(self, date_start=False, date_stop=False, configs=False):
    if not configs:
        configs = self.env['pos.config'].search([])

    orders = self.env['pos.order'].search([
        ('date_order', '>=', date_start),
        ('date_order', '<=', date_stop),
        ('state', 'in', ['paid', 'invoiced', 'done']),
        ('config_id', 'in', configs.ids)])

    products_sold = {}
    for order in orders:
        jour = ''
        jour_list = []
        for statement in order.statement_ids:
            if statement.journal_id.name not in jour_list:
                jour_list.append(statement.journal_id.name)
                jour += statement.journal_id.name + ','
        for line in order.lines:
            seller_name = self.env["res.partner"].search(
                [('id', '=', line.order_id.partner_id.id)]).name

            if products_sold.get(line.product_id.id):
                # print('1111111', line.product.id)
                products_sold[line.product_id.id] = sorted([{
                    'order_date': order.date_order,
                    'product_id': products_sold[line.product_id.id].get('product_id'),
                    'product_name': products_sold[line.product_id.id].get('product_name'),
                    'quantity': products_sold[line.product_id.id].get('quantity', 0) + line.qty,
                    'product_cost': products_sold[line.product_id.id].get('product_cost'),
                    'price_unit': products_sold[line.product_id.id].get('price_unit'),
                    'remaining_qty': line.product_id.qty_available,
                    'seller_name': seller_name,
                    'jour': jour
                } for (product, seller_name, order, line, jour), qty in products_sold.get(line.product_id.id)],key=lambda l: l['order_date'])
            else:
                products_sold[line.product_id.id] = {
                    'order_date': order.date_order,
                    'product_id': line.product_id.id,
                    'product_name': line.product_id.name,
                    'quantity': line.qty,
                    'product_cost': line.product_id.standard_price,
                    'price_unit': line.price_unit,
                    'remaining_qty': line.product_id.qty_available,
                    'seller_name': seller_name,
                    'jour': jour
                }
    return {'products': products_sold}
```

Comment: Fix typo in title: dictionary instead of dictonary

Comment: Hello, please add an example of what you are trying to achieve. You are trying to sort a dict? by which field?  how do you want the dict to look in the end?

Comment: @ExtraFishness bro i have mentioned there... yeah bro you are right i want to sort a dict... field name "order_date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is wrong:

```
for (product, seller_name, order, line, jour), qty in products_sold.get(line.product_id.id)
```

You are iterating the value of `products_sold.get(line.product_id.id)` and expecting that each item contains a sequence of 5 variables. The value of `products_sold.get(line.product_id.id)` is a dict:

```
whole_dict = products_sold.get(line.product_id.id)  # Let's say id=2412
print(type(whole_dict), whole_dict)
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'> {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 13, 59, 33, 351000), 'product_id': 2412, 'product_name': 'ORION HEXA SILVER 19.8*22. SPAIN 355', 'quantity': -4.0, 'product_cost': 0.58, 'price_unit': 1.25, 'remaining_qty': 129.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد برغش المطيري المحترم ', 'jour': 'Cash,'}
```

Which means that iterating `products_sold.get(line.product_id.id)` is equivalent to iterating the keys `products_sold.get(line.product_id.id).keys()` which are just strings:

```
for key in products_sold.get(line.product_id.id):  # Equivalent to products_sold.get(line.product_id.id).keys()
    print(type(key), key)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'> order_date
<class 'str'> product_id
<class 'str'> product_name
<class 'str'> quantity
<class 'str'> product_cost
<class 'str'> price_unit
<class 'str'> remaining_qty
<class 'str'> seller_name
<class 'str'> jour
```

So what you were trying to do is assign each string to those 5 variables:

```
(product, seller_name, order, line, jour), qty = "order_date"
(product, seller_name, order, line, jour), qty = "product_id"
(product, seller_name, order, line, jour), qty = "product_name"
# and so on ...
```

Obviously, they will not fit, which is why you are experiencing the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

### Solution

Here is how you would sort all the `products_sold` based on their `order_date` attribute.

```
import datetime

products_sold = {
    2516: {
        'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 16, 10, 10, 461000),
        'product_id': 2516,
        'product_name': 'TRENTO GRIS 30*60 NEW TILE SPAIN 514',
        'quantity': -1.0,
        'product_cost': 4.0,
        'price_unit': 5.5,
        'remaining_qty': -23.0,
        'seller_name': 'السيد ابو فهد',
        'jour': 'Cash,'
    },
    2412: {
        'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 13, 59, 33, 351000),
        'product_id': 2412,
        'product_name': 'ORION HEXA SILVER 19.8*22. SPAIN 355',
        'quantity': -4.0,
        'product_cost': 0.58,
        'price_unit': 1.25,
        'remaining_qty': 129.0,
        'seller_name': 'السيد برغش المطيري المحترم ',
        'jour': 'Cash,'
    },
    2897: {
        'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 4, 2, 939000),
        'product_id': 2897,
        'product_name': 'BLANCO BR RECT LA 30*60 SPAIN 456',
        'quantity': -6.0,
        'product_cost': 3.5,
        'price_unit': 4.0,
        'remaining_qty': 6.0,
        'seller_name': 'السيد احمد منصور العازمي',
        'jour': 'Cash,'
    },
    2828: {
        'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 8, 38, 380000),
        'product_id': 2828,
        'product_name': 'كاونتر مدور رمادي فاتح 1277 (36*12 CM',
        'quantity': -1.0,
        'product_cost': 0.0,
        'price_unit': 27.5,
        'remaining_qty': -1.0,
        'seller_name': 'السيد علي المطيري المحترم',
        'jour': 'Cash,'
    },
    3041: {
        'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 7, 11, 189000),
        'product_id': 3041,
        'product_name': 'PRIS TINENZA 30*60 SPAIN',
        'quantity': -2.0,
        'product_cost': 5.0,
        'price_unit': 6.5,
        'remaining_qty': -13.0,
        'seller_name': 'السيد محمد حسن الكندري المحترم',
        'jour': 'Cash,'
    },
}

# .items() is a tuple of (key, value), where key (accessed via [0]) is an int e.g. 2897 and value (accessed via [1]) is a dict e.g. {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 4, 2, 939000), 'product_id': 2897, 'product_name': 'BLANCO BR RECT...}
products_sold = dict(
    sorted(
        products_sold.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['order_date']
    )
)

print("Whole dict")
print(products_sold)

print("\n==========\n")

print("Dict items")
for key, value in products_sold.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Output:

```
Whole dict
{2897: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 4, 2, 939000), 'product_id': 2897, 'product_name': 'BLANCO BR RECT LA 30*60 SPAIN 456', 'quantity': -6.0, 'product_cost': 3.5, 'price_unit': 4.0, 'remaining_qty': 6.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد احمد منصور العازمي', 'jour': 'Cash,'}, 3041: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 7, 11, 189000), 'product_id': 3041, 'product_name': 'PRIS TINENZA 30*60 SPAIN', 'quantity': -2.0, 'product_cost': 5.0, 'price_unit': 6.5, 'remaining_qty': -13.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد محمد حسن الكندري المحترم', 'jour': 'Cash,'}, 2828: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 8, 38, 380000), 'product_id': 2828, 'product_name': 'كاونتر مدور رمادي فاتح 1277 (36*12 CM', 'quantity': -1.0, 'product_cost': 0.0, 'price_unit': 27.5, 'remaining_qty': -1.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد علي المطيري المحترم', 'jour': 'Cash,'}, 2412: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 13, 59, 33, 351000), 'product_id': 2412, 'product_name': 'ORION HEXA SILVER 19.8*22. SPAIN 355', 'quantity': -4.0, 'product_cost': 0.58, 'price_unit': 1.25, 'remaining_qty': 129.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد برغش المطيري المحترم ', 'jour': 'Cash,'}, 2516: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 16, 10, 10, 461000), 'product_id': 2516, 'product_name': 'TRENTO GRIS 30*60 NEW TILE SPAIN 514', 'quantity': -1.0, 'product_cost': 4.0, 'price_unit': 5.5, 'remaining_qty': -23.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد ابو فهد', 'jour': 'Cash,'}}

==========

Dict items
2897 {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 4, 2, 939000), 'product_id': 2897, 'product_name': 'BLANCO BR RECT LA 30*60 SPAIN 456', 'quantity': -6.0, 'product_cost': 3.5, 'price_unit': 4.0, 'remaining_qty': 6.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد احمد منصور العازمي', 'jour': 'Cash,'}
3041 {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 7, 11, 189000), 'product_id': 3041, 'product_name': 'PRIS TINENZA 30*60 SPAIN', 'quantity': -2.0, 'product_cost': 5.0, 'price_unit': 6.5, 'remaining_qty': -13.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد محمد حسن الكندري المحترم', 'jour': 'Cash,'}
2828 {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 23, 20, 8, 38, 380000), 'product_id': 2828, 'product_name': 'كاونتر مدور رمادي فاتح 1277 (36*12 CM', 'quantity': -1.0, 'product_cost': 0.0, 'price_unit': 27.5, 'remaining_qty': -1.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد علي المطيري المحترم', 'jour': 'Cash,'}
2412 {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 13, 59, 33, 351000), 'product_id': 2412, 'product_name': 'ORION HEXA SILVER 19.8*22. SPAIN 355', 'quantity': -4.0, 'product_cost': 0.58, 'price_unit': 1.25, 'remaining_qty': 129.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد برغش المطيري المحترم ', 'jour': 'Cash,'}
2516 {'order_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 16, 10, 10, 461000), 'product_id': 2516, 'product_name': 'TRENTO GRIS 30*60 NEW TILE SPAIN 514', 'quantity': -1.0, 'product_cost': 4.0, 'price_unit': 5.5, 'remaining_qty': -23.0, 'seller_name': 'السيد ابو فهد', 'jour': 'Cash,'}
```

Sample run:

- https://paiza.io/projects/e/S4DaFd3efAcbx3SesvMTsA?theme=twilight

This assumes that you are using Python 3.7 or later, as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) since only from that version are dictionaries ordered. Otherwise, use a list (or collections.OrderedDict), so change above to `list(sorted(...`.

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion
> order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

Comment: "bro it is giving error in the if statment:"

 
        if products_sold.get(line.product_id.id):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Your `products_sold` is a dict right as in my example? You can view the sample run here: https://paiza.io/projects/e/S4DaFd3efAcbx3SesvMTsA?theme=twilight

Comment: "and also if i change:"
products_sold = sorted(
    products_sold[line.product_id.id], key=lambda item: item[1]['order_date']
)
its gives error:
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable
 
i changed itb as because dict was on products_sold[line.product_id.id]

Comment: Could you update the question and add the exact format of `products_sold`? Is it as how it is now  `products_sold =  {2516: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(), product_id': 2516}, 2412: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(), product_id': 2412}}` or is it `products_sold =  [{2516: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(), product_id': 2516}, 2412: {'order_date': datetime.datetime(), product_id': 2412}}]` or some other?

Comment: no no its alright bro you are right.. i just previously converted the dict to list and forgot to change it back so it was giving error

Comment: bro can you please say me what exactly you corrected that...

Comment: Aside from the mentioned problem with the way the dictionary keys (which are just single `str` objects) was iterated, accessed, and assigned to the 5 variables resulting to the `too many values to unpack` problem, the correction is just we need to iterate across each product, get its product->order_date and use it as the basis of the sort, then recreate the original dict. It has the same idea as your initial work, only that we corrected the usage of the involved data structures.